# how do I get the depth of a MenuLinkContent?

Tags: 8, navigation

I'm using the sitemap module and i need to get the menu link depth in my preprocess function (template_sitemap_menu_link). I'm trying to do that by accessing the MenuLinkContent object with

```
    $menu_link_obj = $variables['element']['#original_link'];
```

There is a getParent() method I can access to check if this is a level zero item, but no way to check for depth. I could always loop trough getParent() until I get NULL and count the number of iterations, but that seems like a bad practise to me. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Here is our approach:

```
$menu_link = $variables['element']['#original_link'];

$depth = 0;
$parent = $menu_link->getParent();
if ($parent) {
  while ($parent) {
    $parent_parts = explode(':', $parent);

    $parent_entity = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid($parent_parts[0], $parent_parts[1]);
    $parent = $parent_entity->get('parent')->get(0)->value;
    $depth ++;
  }
}
```

Hope to help

Comment: Anyone coming across this, it will cause an error when trying to access the value for `$parent_entity`. Use `$parent = $parent_entity->get('parent')->get(0) ? $parent_entity->get('parent')->get(0)->value : NULL;` will solve this, that we check for the parent first.